# '-(NSString *)description' method of NSManagedObject's to-many relationship causes crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, many-to-many, nsmanagedobject

Very weird issue is happening to my app with CoreData.

Entity A has a To-Many relationship to entity B and the inverse relationship is also To-many. The relationships are optional both ways, deletions rules are Nullify.

Now A records have beed inserted with no B relationships, `NSManagedObjectContext` is saved without error. Then I fetch an A object and try to `NSLog` it which ends up with exception:

```
-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I do not override `- (NSString *)description` method and I do not have any custom getters in A class so I have no idea why it throws this exception. Interestingly, when I do 'print object' of `[aObject.bRelationship allObjects]` in a debugger it does print an empty array, but `[aObject bRelationship]` throws that exception.

I've tried using -com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1 which didn't really tell anything helpful.

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1:**

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];


    [[SyncManager shared] setupCoreDataStack];

    @try {
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"MyEntity"];
        request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title != nil"];
        NSError *error;
        MyEntity *object = [[[SyncManager shared].context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] lastObject];

        NSLog(@"object: %@, error: %@", object, error);
        NSLog(@"relationship.allObject: %@", object.collections.allObjects);
        NSLog(@"relationship: %@", object.collections);
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"exception : %@", exception);
    }
    @finally {
        NSLog(@"Stack trace : %@",[NSThread callStackSymbols]);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[45502:60b] object: <MyEntity: 0x10a7e360> (entity: MyEntity; id: 0x10a6f380 <x-coredata://457EDA6A-5890-4CC8-8997-A734E89D68C0/MyEntity/p106> ; data: <fault>), error: (null)
[45502:60b] relationship.allObject: (
    )
[45502:60b] -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10862f40
[45502:60b] exception : -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10862f40
[45502:60b] Stack trace : (
        0   MyApp                               0x001e3bb3 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 1603
        1   UIKit                               0x04ae314f -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 309
        2   UIKit                               0x04ae3aa1 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1810
        3   UIKit                               0x04ae8667 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
        4   UIKit                               0x04afcf92 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3517
        5   UIKit                               0x04afd555 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
        6   UIKit                               0x04aea250 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 683
        7   GraphicsServices                    0x0833af02 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
        8   GraphicsServices                    0x0833aa0d PurpleEventCallback + 46
        9   CoreFoundation                      0x06fb9ca5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
        10  CoreFoundation                      0x06fb99db __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
        11  CoreFoundation                      0x06fe468c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
        12  CoreFoundation                      0x06fe39d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
        13  CoreFoundation                      0x06fe37eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
        14  UIKit                               0x04ae7d9c -[UIApplication _run] + 840
        15  UIKit                               0x04ae9f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
        16  MyApp                               0x0000897c main + 76
        17  libdyld.dylib                       0x07587701 start + 1
        18  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
    )
```

**MyEntity.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class B;

@interface MyEntity : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *collections;
@end

@interface MyEntity (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addCollectionsObject:(B *)value;
- (void)removeCollectionsObject:(B *)value;
- (void)addCollections:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeCollections:(NSSet *)values;
@end
```

Comment: Can you show the stack backtrace from the exception? Some code (how you fetch and NSLog the object) might also be helpful.

Comment: I've updated my question with more details.

Comment: Can you show the contents of MyEntity.h ?